# Assign item in list an ID

Tags: c#

I have three lists called `dynamicTextEnumsInDatabase`, `dynamicTextEnumsAll`, and `dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable`.

I'm trying to add items to the `dynamicTextEnumsAll` list based on all of the possible Enums that can be used in my `DynamicTextEnum` class. I'm able to add all of them, however the numbers do not match up. For example in the class, the `EnumMembers` start at 1 whereas the lists starts at 0.

In my `DynamicTextEnum` class I have the following members:

```
    [EnumMember]
    Agreement = 1,

    [EnumMember]
    Warning = 2,

    [EnumMember]
    Reminder = 3
```

However in the `dynamicTextEnumsAll` list they appear as:

```
Agreement = 0, Warning = 1, Reminder = 2
```

Where in the below code could I assign them values while adding them. I've already tried having a counter int and assign them this way:

`dynamicTextEnumsAll.Add(item[counter]);`

### Code

```
List<DynamicTextEnum> dynamicTextEnumsInDatabase = new List<DynamicTextEnum>();
List<DynamicTextEnum> dynamicTextEnumsAll = new List<DynamicTextEnum>();

foreach (DynamicTextEnum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DynamicTextEnum)))
{
    dynamicTextEnumsAll.Add(item);
}

using (var proxy = new Proxy<IDynamicText>())
{
    dynamicTextEnumsInDatabase = proxy.Channel.DynamicTextGetActiveEnums(Helper.GetCallingUser());
}

List<DynamicTextEnum> dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable = dynamicTextEnumsAll.Except(dynamicTextEnumsInDatabase).ToList();

if (dynamicTextEnumsAvaiable.Count == 0)
{
    TempData["Error"] = "To update a message or warning please select it from the grid below.";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. I just ended up creating a class for the records that were returned from the database and then converting them to the Enums.

Answer (score 0):

The number you're showing from `dynamicTextEnumsAll` is just the 0-based index position of the item in your `List`, and has nothing to do with the underlying integer value of your enumeration.

To get the underlying integer value, you can cast back to an int.

For example, you indicated that DynamicTextEnum.Agreement is position 0 in your list, so the following should return 1:

```
var underlyingEnumValue = (int)dynamicTextEnumsAll[0];
```